# Example of "copy_from_user" in Linux Kernel (just copying a pointer to an int)

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

I know there are a lot of posts on this, but most are very complex and I'm hoping someone can help me with my simple example.

I'm writing a system call and the function I'm writing has the form:

```
SYS_CALLDEFINE4(calc, int, param1, int, param2, char, operation, int*, result) 
{
//Do system call stuff here
}
```

I know that the pointer to the int will be a problem, because the userspace application could have passed a pointer to vital system space (and we don't want to mess with that). So I need to use the `copy_from_user` function.

Can someone possibly give an example of how to correctly use those two functions in the context of making sure you can access that pointer correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacement for

```
*result = <value>;
```

would be

```
int local_value = <value>;
if (copy_to_user(&local_value, result, sizeof(*result)))
{
    // 'result' points to inaccessible memory.
}
// assigning 'result' has been successful.
```

Alternatively, because the size of the `result` is small (`int` in your case), you may use `put_user`, which is simpler and more effective:

```
if (put_user(<value>, result) < 0)
{
    // 'result' points to inaccessible memory.
}
// assigning 'result' has been successful.
```

Comment: Let's say I update the value that the pointer 'result' is pointing to. Would I, in this case, need a `copy_to_user` call? My intuition is no, because I'm not giving the user back a pointer that I declared in kernel space. My understanding is that `copy_to_user` is only used in that scenario.